how to fix the: "Oracle price status is not trading" to retreive funds from Port Finance
I have hit a problem with a code that worked few weeks ago.
"Oracle price status is not trading".
I am trying to update port finance reserves, but it seems the PYTH oracle is not trading?
Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x2a", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, Custom(42))), logs: Some(["Program Port7uDYB3wk6GJAw4KT1WpTeMtSu9bTcChBHkX2LfR invoke [1]", "Program log: Instruction: Refresh Reserve", "Program log: Oracle price status is not trading", "Program log: Input oracle config is invalid", "Program Port7uDYB3wk6GJAw4KT1WpTeMtSu9bTcChBHkX2LfR consumed 16373 of 200000 compute units", "Program Port7uDYB3wk6GJAw4KT1WpTeMtSu9bTcChBHkX2LfR failed: custom program error: 0x2a"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(16373), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) }

Port Finance webpage is not working, but the funds can be saved.
I have successfully set up rust code following https://crates.io/crates/port-variable-rate-lending-instructions
I could not sign big instructructions in RUST with ledger so i serialized them in RUST
    let serializable_instructions: Vec<SerializableInstruction> = instructions
.iter()
.map(|ix| SerializableInstruction {
    program_id: ix.program_id.to_string(),
    accounts: ix
        .accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|acc| SerializableAccountMeta {
            pubkey: acc.pubkey.to_string(),
            is_signer: acc.is_signer,
            is_writable: acc.is_writable,
        })
        .collect(),
    data: ix.data.clone(),
})
.collect();

let tx_json = serde_json::to_string(&serializable_instructions).unwrap();
let mut file = File::create("instructions.json").unwrap();
file.write_all(tx_json.as_bytes()).unwrap();

and then used javascript with phantom wallet to sign and send them to blockchain
<script>
    let instructionsData = null;

    // Handle file input change
    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            try {
                instructionsData = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
                console.log("Loaded instructions:", instructionsData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
                alert("Invalid JSON file.");
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    });

    // Function to sign and send the transaction
    async function signTransaction() {
        if (!instructionsData) {
            alert('Please upload a JSON file with instructions.');
            return;
        }

        const { Connection, PublicKey, Transaction, TransactionInstruction } = solanaWeb3;

        const instructions = instructionsData.map(ix => new TransactionInstruction({
            programId: new PublicKey(ix.program_id),
            keys: ix.accounts.map(acc => ({
                pubkey: new PublicKey(acc.pubkey),
                isSigner: acc.is_signer,
                isWritable: acc.is_writable
            })),
            data: new Uint8Array(ix.data)
        }));

        console.log("Parsed instructions:", instructions);

        const transaction = new Transaction();
        instructions.forEach(ix => transaction.add(ix));

        const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
            'https://quaint-yolo-spree.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/******API KEY*****/',
            'confirmed'
        );

        const solana = window.solana;
        if (solana && solana.isPhantom) {
            try {
                await solana.connect();
                const provider = solana;

                const recentBlockhash = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
                transaction.recentBlockhash = recentBlockhash.blockhash;
                transaction.feePayer = provider.publicKey;

                const signed = await provider.signTransaction(transaction);
                const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signed.serialize());
                await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);

                console.log('Transaction sent with signature:', signature);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error signing or sending transaction:', err);
                if (err.logs) {
                    err.logs.forEach(log => console.log(log));
                }
                alert('Error processing the transaction.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Phantom Wallet not found');
        }
    }
</script>


Same issue here, I checked the github to see if there was any change on pyth side but looks like it should return "trading"
